# ssrs 2008 extra page at end - checked usual suspects - how to find cause?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I can't seem to figure out what i'm doing wrong here...thought I might be overlooking something not common as the cause for this so I decided to post a thread.

Report is set for 8.5 x 11 with .25" margins on all sides

Body is 7.89 x 2.90 with all padding set to 0 for report items.

I use a footer but it is the correct width.

I use a hidden detail row that expands from my normal detail row, but the overall width is still less than 8".

I attempted to make a new report and copy the reportitems over so that if I had made a configuration issue I might find it. But the new report behaves the same as the original one I did.

ConsumeContainerWhitespace is True. The tablix on my report is the only item that can page break after and that option is unchecked.

I changed my footer to not appear on last page and it still leaves a blank page for me.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you get us a copy of the RDL?

Comment: is raw xml ok or do I need to make a report project with just that report and a demo db and zip that all together? If xml is ok then look here https://docs.google.com/document/d/19zQTqlAiPf89O4yzbRYW0dE01k2V-KncwkIlP7sthSk/edit

Comment: Running the report you shared with one record doesn't seem to recreate the problem. Is is only for certain formats? How many records are usually in this report?  Sample data used:
 ` SELECT 
1 TrayID,
'OK' TrayStatus,
'1111ASDF' SKU,
'A' AssgndChute,
'B' ReturnCode,
'ShortDescHere' ShortDescription,
1 TrayAssgndTS,
'Other' TrayUnassgndTS,
1000 RevolutionCount,
1 RowID, 
'Big' PackageType,
33 TrayLag,
1 RecordID,
23 PreviousReturnCode,
'LivingRoom' PhysicalLocation`

Comment: Normally there is about 400 rows. I've only tested for my issue in the browser report viewer and the blank page always follows the end of the grid. No visible extra space is between the grid and the footer that would be part of a 2nd page though.

Answer (score 1):

I know it may sound funny..but i have tried this many times whenever I got some issue like this..and I resolved the issue..
sometimes the report object may extend in length by very small inch..and you cant find out that..
What you can try is:--Give some background color to the object such as tablix and then render the report in some format like PDF..if its length giving you next page then the some part of color you can see on that next(blank) page..from that you can get idea about the size of perticular report item which is causing the issue.

I hope this will help you..

Comment: I understand what you are saying. I will give that a shot.

Answer (score 0):

I had to throw out the current copy of this report and recreate it. 2nd time through I didn't get the extra space causing the extra page. I wish I could have figured out what caused it because the hand grenade approach is not the one I always like to take.